# Automatically Process meeting requests setting with MS Outlook 2010 and 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, lotus-notes

Question about this auto-accept invite in Outlook . When you manually accept an invite it gets added to calendar and then the e-mail vanishes from inbox.

Now with auto-accept , I think the e-mail will still vanish ( please correct me if I am wrong) and for users who manage everything from inbox they may get blind sided and may not see that calendar entry.

How do we deal with that.

I think that if auto-accept is enabled then users should make it a habit to monitor their calendar. Or disable it and continue to monitor their inbox

I need your opinion on if e-mails do vanish with auto-accept also and another thing is does auto-accept work with invites coming from any messaging system. on google their is a setting auto-accept invites from gmail.

we send invites using lotus notes and they don't get auto accepted in outlook
however when we send invites using our google apps for work calendar they get auto accepted for same client.

thanks

BRK